# How to setup .Net application to write to Windows share

Tags: c#, .net, iis, permissions

I have a .Net 4.0 App on an IIS 7 machine that needs to write a file out to a Windows share on a seperate server. I have IIS setup to impersonate and made sure my user account has write permission to the location on the other server. However, when I run my app through a browser, I get a login prompt and after entering in my credentials, I get a 401 stating

```
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.
```

I am sure the password I am entering is correct, but this only happens after I start my app (I can direct to the web page, but when I click the button to run the app I get this)

I have also tried to take off impersonate in IIS, but when I run the app, I get a 500 error, with the error log on the server saying

```
An unhandled access exception has occurred.
```

I am stumped on what the issue could be, but I know its probably a permissions issue in IIS. Any help would be appreciated, and let me know if more information is needed.

**EDIT**

I went out to the server the app is deployed on, and I am able to run the app to write the file through IIS browse with no issue. However if I try to run the app from my desktop through a browser, I get an error.

I ran procmon and the events are the exact same, same user, everything, the only difference is the result. I imagine this is a hopping issue, but I am unsure how to fix the issue. Thanks

Comment: Set the AppPool to use your user account

Comment: @StefanP. nope same issue, and I dont think I want to do that long term. do i need to use something other than AppPoolIdentity?

Comment: Have you seen this post, I think it might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539142/impersonation-not-working-network-share

Comment: @Johnny my apppool is already Classic, I am unsure on the rest. How do I grant the ASP .Net user on one server to have write access to another server?

Comment: Do you have your IIS App (authentication) set to use "Windows Authentication" and not Anonymous? Then make sure the [windows authentication] [Advanced Settings] is using NTLM first (Move Up) because it transports to other machines more easily.

Comment: StephanP and Johnny had a good ideas.  If your two servers are on a domain, you can set the AppPool (Advanced settings) to run as "NetworkService".  Then you can grant permissions to  DomainName\YourServerName$.  (including the $, but not the .)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this was the fix but I got it working,

I setup the App Pool to run as Network Service, enabled impersonation, but turned off windows auth in the authentication section. not sure why that setting would cause this issue